# What happens when I call truncate(0) while using picamera library in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, picamera

```py
    def CameraInit(self): 
        self.camera = PiCamera()
        self.camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        self.camera.framerate = 32
        rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera, size=(640, 480))
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        time.sleep(2) # wait for camera starting 

        return self.camera, rawCapture
```

The above is the method I defined when initializing the camera. By the way, what is the data type of rawcapture?

No other attempt has been made. If there is another way to try when encountering this kind of problem, I will ask humbly.

Comment: You might want to read the [docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_array.html#picamera.array.PiArrayOutput.truncate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for! For a beginner with python, where to find information is always a headache! Thank you again for your answer!